# Integrating VOIP functionality in a native iOS app and using it in React Native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, voip, callkit

I am working on a project where I need to integrate VOIP functionality into a native iOS app and then use it in a React Native app. I've followed several guides and third-party libraries, but I'm encountering issues.

I've installed the necessary libraries using react-native link.
https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-voip-push-notification.git
https://github.com/ajith-ab/react-native-voip-call.git

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.